# Meu código JavaScript para alterar visibilidade não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Escrevi um formulário com estes elementos:

```
<div>
    <label for="radio_pessoa_fisica" id="label_cpf_req">
        <input name="pessoa" id="radio_pessoa_fisica" type="radio" value="fisica" required>
        Pessoa Física
    </label>
    <label for="radio_pessoa_juridica" id="label_cnpj_req">
        <input name="pessoa" id="radio_pessoa_juridica" type="radio" value="juridica" required>
        Pessoa Jurídica
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="cpf_req">
        CPF
        <input id="cpf_req" type="text" placeholder="000.000.000-00" required maxlength="14" pattern="([0-9][.-]?){3,11}">
    </label>
    <label for="cnpj_req" id="label_cnpj_req" >
        CNPJ
        <input id="cnpj_req" type="text" placeholder="00.000.000/0000-00" required maxlength="18">
    </label>
</div>
```

E lá ao final, antes de fechar o body, a tag `<script>` que chama o seguinte código:

```
function radio_pessoa_change() {
    var pfis = document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").checked;
    document.getElementById("label_cpf_req").style.display = pfis ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("label_cnpj_req").style.display = pfis ? "none" : "block";
    document.getElementById("req_rep").disabled = !pfis;
    if (!pfis) {
        document.getElementById("req_rep").checked = true
    }
}

document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").addEventListener("change", radio_pessoa_change);
document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_juridica").addEventListener("change", radio_pessoa_change);
document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").checked = true;
```

No entanto, quando navego para a página do formulário, o input `#radio_pessoa_fisica` é checado pelo script, mas o manipulador de evento não é chamado, e ambos os inputs de texto, `#cpf_req` e `#cnpj_req` ficam visíveis.

Somente clicando nos inputs rádio na própria página é que a função é chamada e faz o que se espera.

Alguém pode me explicar por que isso acontece, e se possível, me ajudar a obter o efeito desejado (que a function `radio_pessoa_change()` seja executada e oculte o input `#cnpj_req`

Por favor, agradeço se as respostas se ativerem a JavaScript puro.

Comment: Olá, @RiscadoOoOoO e RabiscadoO. Estou iniciando em JavaScript, poderia me explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "evento exclusivo"? Obrigado!

Comment: Ja tentou adicionar um EvenListener pro evento de 'click' ao invés de change?

Comment: @DimitriusLachi, já, mas mesmo assim, não pega a definição feita pelo script inicial.

Comment: Na verdade, o problema não é tão sério, posso definir a visibilidade dos inputs de texto no script inicial, também. Só fiquei intrigado com o fato de que o evento change não é acionado quando mudo o valor do "checked". Esses eventos, eles são limitados a ações provenientes da UI da página renderizada?

Comment: Uma pergunta, você tem certeza que seus eventListeners estão sendo atribuídos? Coloque um debugger antes de fazer adicionar os event listeners e veja se eles estão sendo adicionados

Comment: @DimitriusLachi, tenho certeza porque depois que a página carrega, eles respondem aos cliques.

Comment: Estou aprendendo JavaScript, e já tenho que aprontar esse formulário. No futuro quero aprender JQuery também, mas agora tenho medo de me enrolar...

Comment: Enviei uma possibilidade abaixo

Comment: Troque o evento por `click` em vez de `change` e altere para: `document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").click();`

Comment: @Sam, sua solução funcionou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O evento `change` só é disparado com ação do usuário. Fica mais fácil trocando por `click` que poderá ser disparado também via código usando o método `.click()`:

```
document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").addEventListener("click", radio_pessoa_change);
document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_juridica").addEventListener("click", radio_pessoa_change);
document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você esta escondendo a label do radio button, e não o input de CPF/CPNJ.
Tente trocar sua função `radio_pessoa_change`

```
function radio_pessoa_change() {
  var pfis = document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").checked;
  document.getElementById("cpf_req").style.display = pfis ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("cnpj_req").style.display = pfis ? "none" : "block";
  document.getElementById("req_rep").disabled = !pfis;
  if (!pfis) {
    document.getElementById("req_rep").checked = true
  }
}
```

Lembre-se de esconder também o texto, 'CPNJ' e 'CPF'

Comment: como os inputs estão dentro dos labels, eu escondo os labels pra que o texto e os campos sumam juntos

Comment: Você esta escondendo as labels dos radios buttons e não dos campos de CPF e CNPJ, veja os ids que esta usando, vc esconde as labels dos dois radios, se precisa esconder os campos de digitação, troque sua função pela que descrevi na resposta

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui fazer funcionar mudando o manipulador pra capturar o evento "click" (como você tinha sugerido), e depois mudar o meu comando de `document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").checked = true;` pra `document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").click();`

Comment: Show de bola. espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você esta com um `id` duplicado, e pelo que me parece você quer dar hide no `input text` e não no `radio button`. Por isso eu colocaria os `ids` nas labels dos `input text`, ao final eu coloquei uma chamada da sua função para que a  primeira vez ele esconda o cnpj ficando assim:

```js
function radio_pessoa_change() {
    var pfis = document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").checked;
    document.getElementById("label_cpf_req").style.display = pfis ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("label_cnpj_req").style.display = pfis ? "none" : "block";
    document.getElementById("req_rep").disabled = !pfis;
    if (!pfis) {
        document.getElementById("req_rep").checked = true
    }
}

document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").addEventListener("change", radio_pessoa_change);
document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_juridica").addEventListener("change", radio_pessoa_change);
document.getElementById("radio_pessoa_fisica").checked = true;

radio_pessoa_change();
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="radio_pessoa_fisica">
        <input name="pessoa" id="radio_pessoa_fisica" type="radio" value="fisica" required>
        Pessoa Física
    </label>
    <label for="radio_pessoa_juridica">
        <input name="pessoa" id="radio_pessoa_juridica" type="radio" value="juridica" required>
        Pessoa Jurídica
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="cpf_req"   id="label_cpf_req">
        CPF
        <input id="cpf_req" type="text" placeholder="000.000.000-00" required maxlength="14" pattern="([0-9][.-]?){3,11}">
    </label>
    <label for="cnpj_req" id="label_cnpj_req" >
        CNPJ
        <input id="cnpj_req" type="text" placeholder="00.000.000/0000-00" required maxlength="18">
    </label>
</div>
```

Apenas editei o `HTML` o javascript esta como você publicou exceto pela adição da chamada da `radio_pessoa_change` no final